# Get a parameter

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, python-3.x

I got a function that draws circles and makes random answer
(answer here is a number between 1-100)

```
def circle(x,y,ans):
    #RandomAnswer
    global RaAns
    RaAns = random.randint(1, 100)
    tr.up()
    #center of circle is: (x,y)
    tr.goto(x,y-40)
    tr.down()
    tr.fill(1)
    tr.color(0.2,0.2,0.2)
    tr.circle(40)
    tr.color(0.2,0.6,0.6)
    tr.fill(0)
    tr.up()
    tr.goto(x-15,y-15)
    tr.down()
    tr.color(0.2,0.2,0.2)
    tr.write(RaAns,font=("Ariel",20))
```

and i got that aswell:

```
C1 = circle(150,245,RaAns)
C2 = circle(245,150,RaAns)
```

my question is how do I pick C1 `RaAns` and how do I pick C2 `RaAns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; They have been re-assigned to a new number. That is, when get `C2`, `RaAns` has been reassigned. The way you should do this is either return RaAns or forgo it entirely and use that `ans` parameter.

```
def circle(x, y, ans=None):
    if ans is None:
        ans = random.randint(1, 100)
    ...
    tr.write(ans, font=("Arial", 20))
    return ans

C = [None] * 3
C[1] = circle(150, 245)
C[2] = circle(245, 150)

# C is now [None, *C1's random number*, *C2's random number*]
```

If you have to return something else, pre-make the random number.

```
def circle(x, y, ans):
    ...
    tr.write(ans, font=("Arial", 20))
    return something

C = [{}, {"rand": random.randint(1, 100)}, {"rand": random.randint(1, 100)}]
C[1]["circle"] = circle(150, 245, C[1]["rand"])
C[2]["circle"] = circle(245, 150, C[2]["rand"])

# C is now [None,
#           {"rand": *C1's random number*, "circle": *What circle returned*},
#           {"rand": *C2's random number*, "circle": *What circle returned*}]
```

Comment: sorry to bother you again but an Error accords 'IndentationError: expected an indented block'

Comment: @LironLavi You probably forgot some spaces somewhere, after an `if` or `while` statement

Comment: line 49
    C[1]["circle"] = circle(150,245, C[1]["rand"])
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block